# separable degree and the radical exponent

Tags: field-theory

Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over $F$, where $charF=p\neq0$  and let $d$ be the radical exponent of $\alpha$. (which means $\alpha$ has multiplicity $p^d$)

I am trying to show the following expression;

$\alpha$$^{p^k}$ is separable over $F$ if and only if $k\geq d$.

Comment: I am taking the radical exponent to mean that $p^{d}$ is the smallest integer such that $\alpha^{p^{d}} \in F$. Is that correct?

Comment: It is defined to be the largest integer $d$ for which
$p(x)=q(x^{p^d})$ where $p(x)=min(\alpha,F)$.

Comment: Ok. In that case, one direction of the result should follow. If $k < d$, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^{p^{k}}$ should just be $p$ with $x$ replaced with $x^{p^{k}}$, which is possible because every non constant monomial in the polynomial is divided by $x^{p^{k}}$. But this new polynomial is also inseparable because it consists only of $p$th powers in the exponents.